# is there any chance to change projection for geojson(mapshaper)

Tags: openlayers, geojson, projection, map-projections, mapshaper

- Hello all,
- i am using OpenLayers 5, Angular 6, mapshaper tool(converting shp to json).
- [MapshaperTool](http://mapshaper.org), [Git Code](https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper)

**my process**

- i have installed **npm mapshaper --save**
- i am able to upload different .shp files and able to get json features data.
- i have 2 different .shp files [layer-ind.shp, layer-administration.shp]
- layer-ind.shp file uploaded its json gives like

`{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            75.89355468749999,
            18.521283325496277
          ],
          [
            80.6396484375,
            19.68397023588844
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}`

- layer-us.shp file uploaded its json gives like

`{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type":"Feature",
      "geometry":{
        "type":"LineString",
        "coordinates":[
          [-349771.1875,445307.8125],
          [-349789.6875,445314.375],
          [-349796.5625,445321.5625],
          [-349792.78119999915,445341.4375],
          [-349786.53119999915,445351.71880000085],
          [-349771.1875,445307.8125]]},
      "properties":{
        "TYPE":"ISLAND","RuleID":3,
        "Shape_Leng":544.475438955
      }
    }
  ]
}`

when preview these two layers(features) preview on map
1. layer-ind.json file gives correct results and able see layer on map in correct place
2. layer-us.json file gives wrong place showing on map (0,0)

- how to solve these 2nd point layer-us.json issue, i have change the re-projection also like

`const vectorSource = new VectorSource({
        features: (new GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojson, {
        featureProjection: 'EPSG:4326'
      });
    });`

- i have changed featureProjection code also, but its not working layer-us.json.
- please help on this
- save my days

Comment: layer-us.shp should have a layer-us.prj file. Open it with a text editor and provide its contents.

Comment: this is contents of .prj `PROJCS["NAD_1983_California_Teale_Albers",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Albers"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",-4000000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-120.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",34.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",40.5],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the data projection as well as feature projection.  `featurePprojection` is the projection of your map view.  `dataProjection` is the projection of the coordinates in the json.  I can see that dataProjection for layer-ind is 'EPSG:4326', the dataProjection for layer-us appears to use the coordinates of a local projection.  Do you know which projection or where the island is?

```
const vectorSource = new VectorSource({
        features: (new GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojson, {
        dataProjection: 'xxxx',
        featureProjection: 'yyyy'
      })
    });
```

Based on the projection definition you have now given here's a working sample (to run here it uses full build syntax)

```js
proj4.defs('NAD_1983_California_Teale_Albers', 'PROJCS["NAD_1983_California_Teale_Albers",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Albers"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",-4000000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-120.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",34.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",40.5],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]');

ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

geojson = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
{
  "type":"Feature",
  "geometry":{
    "type":"LineString",
    "coordinates":[
      [-349771.1875,445307.8125],
      [-349789.6875,445314.375],
      [-349796.5625,445321.5625],
      [-349792.78119999915,445341.4375],
      [-349786.53119999915,445351.71880000085],
      [-349771.1875,445307.8125]]},
  "properties":{
    "TYPE":"ISLAND","RuleID":3,
    "Shape_Leng":544.475438955
  }
}
  ]
}

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [ new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM() }) ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View()
});


const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojson, {
    dataProjection: 'NAD_1983_California_Teale_Albers',
    featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection()
  })
});


map.addLayer(new ol.layer.Vector({source: vectorSource}));

map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent());
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.5.0/proj4.js"></script>

<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, i have tried but no luck.. Layer displaying on 0,0 position

Comment: You can't use it until you know the projection and replace 'xxxx' and 'yyyy' with the correctly values.  You will also need to define the projection using proj4.

Comment: i have tried it, `proj4.defs('EPSG:4326',
            '+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 ' +
                '+x_0=600000 +y_0=200000 +ellps=bessel ' +
                    '+towgs84=660.077,13.551,369.344,2.484,1.783,2.939,5.66 +units=m +no_defs');
        register(proj4);
        const swissProjection = getProjection('EPSG:4326'); 
`
then 
`featureProjection: swissProjection `

Comment: try to add this -->`proj4.defs["SR-ORG:10"] = "+proj=aea +lat_1=34 +lat_2=40.5 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-120 +x_0=0 +y_0=-4000000 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs";` and then use within your vector source`dataProjection: 'SR-ORG:10'` found here --> http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/10/

Comment: @pavlos OpenLayers has been able to use WKT definitions directly since version 3 https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/examples/scaleline-indiana-east.html  If you run the snippt the vector is positioned on an island.

Comment: Thats correct. I am a bit confused , user wants to use the projection above but he configures `EPSG:4326` instead the one you propose. So I though to give him a second option.